# create a sub folders in a parent folder with user specified name in a network path specified in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am using below code to create folders and subfolders at batch file location

```
@echo off
MD 1.Inputs 2.Documents 3.Status 4.Production 5.Deliveries 6.Tools 2.Documents\Technical 2.Documents\General 6.Tools\Inputs 6.Tools\Testing
```

Now, I want to have above folders created in a parent folder with user input name but these folders are to be created with parent folder on a network path

i have put in below line to prompt for folder name

```
set /p FOL=enter your folder name:
```

I am not sure, How to combine both the codes and add command to specify network path on a server to create folders

Is there a way to run batch files on the network path from the batch file on a local machine

Thanking you in advance

Kumar

Answer (score 0):

```
set /p FOL=enter your folder name:
```

Leads to a variable %FOL% which you can hand over to the command to create a directory:

```
 md %FOL%
```

You might need to do `cd` before creating the folder.

In case UNC paths don't work on the network share, you can also mount it as a drive letter with [net use](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490717.aspx).